# How can I concatenate 1 arrays & string in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to print a sentence to the Console that reads “My favorite character is {print your favorite character’s name}.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] Myfav = {"Bugs", "Mickey", "Taz", "elmer", "jerry" + "" };
        System.out.println(MyFav[4]);
    };
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **this is** ***homework!!***

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concatenation operator `+`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] my = new String[] {"Bugs", "Mickey", "Taz", "elmer", "jerry"};

    System.out.println("My favorite character is " + my[4]);
}
```

Please, consider properly formatting your code and making sure your code is free of simple mistakes before posting to StackOverflow. Also, you should perform your own research before coming here to ask a question.